# Change <i> when clicked on

Tags: jquery

I have this code but it's only works with `<img>`. It changes the image and adds a value to the checkbox. I would like it to work with `<i class='fa'></i>`. What do I need to change?

```js
$(".img-checkbox").click(function() {
  var img = $(this);
  alert(img.prev().prop('checked'));
  if (img.prev().prop("checked")) {
    img.css({
      'opacity': '0.3'
    });
  } else {
    img.css({
      'opacity': '1.0'
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" name="qRequirements" hidden>
  <i class="fa fa-phone fa-4x" class="img-responsive img-checkbox"></i>
</label>

<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" name="qRequirements" hidden>
  <i class="fa fa-user fa-4x" class="img-responsive img-checkbox"></i>
</label>

<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" name="qRequirements" hidden>
  <i class="fa fa-mail fa-4x" class="img-responsive img-checkbox"></i>
</label>
```

Comment: Could you make the description of your question better? I can't understand the sentences.

Comment: Also note that the [`hidden` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden) is unsupported in <IE11, so you're probably better using `display: none` in CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set `class` two times in your `<i>` elements, making it ignore the second `class` assignment and jQuery will not recognize the elements being clicked. You cannot use an attribute more than once per element. Change

```
<i class="fa fa-user fa-4x" class="img-responsive img-checkbox"></i>
```

to

```
<i class="fa fa-user fa-4x img-responsive img-checkbox"></i>
```

```js
$(".img-checkbox").click(function() {
  var img = $(this);
  if (img.prev().prop("checked")) {
    img.css({
      'opacity': '0.3'
    });
  } else {
    img.css({
      'opacity': '1.0'
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" name="qRequirements" hidden>
    <i class="fa fa-phone fa-4x img-responsive img-checkbox"></i>
</label>

<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" name="qRequirements" hidden>
    <i class="img-responsive img-checkbox fa fa-user fa-4x"></i>
</label>

<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" name="qRequirements" hidden>
    <i class="fa fa-mail fa-4x img-responsive img-checkbox"></i>
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks, but why the checkbox doesn't get value when i click on the <i> element?

Comment: Nothing in your code sets a value for the checkbox. You could add img.prev().val("yourValue"); to set that. @roi